# How to configure IdentityServer4 for existing database users and populate the token with claims

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1

Using with .net Core 3.1 web and creating an IdentitySErvier4 service

I found the documentation http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html

But, Unable to identify, how to configure IdentityServer4 (Startup.cs) for existing Users to validate and populate token with claims.

One other good article went through, https://www.identityserver.com/documentation/adminui/Configuration_and_Integration/Integrating_with_IdentityServer/ , found this following with AccountController to validate users.

//following are memory resource,

```
        services.AddIdentityServer()                    
                .AddClientStoreCache<DatabaseClientStore>()
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(GetStaticIdentityResources()) //how claims shouldbe configure to pull associated to uses and populate
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(GetStaticApiResources())  //how claims shouldbe configure to pull associated to uses and populate
                .AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Users)   //how this can pull from database and configure here to validate.
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
```

Comment: Are you already using Asp.Net Identity with your current app, or do you just have your own custom Users table in the DB?

Comment: Not using, its manual authentication to validate against database table. But, now building up identityserver4 to validate existing users.

Comment: Does this help: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signin.html. Essentially, you would use the `AccountController` to capture the user name / password and validate them against your DB, then use the `HttpContext` to sign in from the user you just verified in your database.